# Using Nemo in Linux Mint to connect to ftp server

Tags: linux-mint, nemo

I have a USB drive connected to my router to access files remotely, and it can use ftp to connect (not ssh or sftp). I have the router login set to the same login as my desktop computer, and I can use Nemo to connect to the server for file transfers only if I set the ftp login to use the same login as my main router login.

But, I have the option to set up an alternate login, which I'd like to do so I don't need to give out the router login to anyone. However, Nemo will not connect using either "Connect to server" or typing in a URL in the address line.  It will only connect if the login name and password are the same as the computer.  I believe there is some protocol for using your existing login for an external device.

It's obviously not the router, as I can connect as expected using my phone's file manager (FX on Android).

EDIT: I tried using a windows share option, and had the same problem. Something about sending the login information doesn't work, except when it's the system's login info.  Even using user:password@address doesn't work; it prompts for a password, but the command it sends is screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

I use this format to access my Android tablet:

- sftp://192.168.xx.yy:2222/storage/extSdCard/Movies

The ftp server (on the Android) doesn't have root access so can't use port 22.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work in this situation, which is that this uses SSH, which isn't available.  Also, the problem isn't connecting, the problem is entering a password on the remote server.  I can connect fine if the remote server has the same password as my local computer.

Comment: @MartyFried hi ya.  the same url should still work with `ftp:sftp://192.168.xx.yy` but as you say connecting is your problem.  Pity you can't put `ssh` on the router.  good luck